# DLL redirect export without using def file

Tags: dll, mingw, codeblocks

Is there some way to instruct MinGW-w64 or CodeBlocks project to generate line in def file like this:
   `func2=func1`

```
int __attribute__((dllimport)) Double (int);
int __attribute__((dllexport,alias("Double"))) NextDouble(int);
```

I thought this will work but compiler emits error:

`|2|error: 'NextDouble' aliased to undefined symbol 'Double'|`

Is there some way to bypass alias to linker?

Clarification:

I have one DLL's import library, which exports Double. I am trying to create second DLL which will import Double and export NextDouble which will point to address of imported Double. So the same thing as if I will do NextDouble=Double in def-file. Which will make export NextDouble in dll point to import Double.

Comment: Are you trying to create a named alias for the function? What is your actual use case? (Add it to your question, not as a comment)

Comment: I think I solved it, when I will try it I will post the whole thing.

Comment: is `Double` from another dll module? You cannot make alias for symbols that reside in another dll.

Comment: Yes, it is :( In the other case it will be easily solved

Comment: It's better if you explain what it is you're trying to solve. Why do you think you need to do something like this?

Comment: I found one thing assembler generates .section .drectve\n .ascii " -export:\"NextDouble\"" so generating drectve section with synonym on cmd can do this.

Comment: If that solved it you should add it as an answer so it helps future visitors.

Comment: I will do, but now I am creating appropriate macro. I got lost escaping it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is preprocessor which can add characters to -o phase command line:

```
#define first ".section .drectve\n.ascii\"
#define last \""
#define addcmd(name) first name last
#define cmd(name) asm(addcmd( name ))
cmd(thingtoadd)
```

So you can add anything that means the def file too to it.

Comment: Can you show what the macro expands into after preprocessing? There's some macros not defined like `linkit`.